# iPad text input and text selecting not working properly

Tags: ios, css, ipad, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

This will be difficult to explain so I won't paste any code.

I'm implementing a wysiwyg editor on my site called wysihtml5 and there are several issues when selecting the textarea/editor with the iPad. On a desktop browser, all is fine, the text can be selected, edited, pasted etc. But on the iPad multpiple issues occur:

1. Can't tap anywhere in the text to move the cursor there
2. If I manually move the cursor, all of a sudden I can't type anything anymore
3. Tapping outside of the texteditor doesn't bring the keyboard down

Basically I'm just hoping there's someone who has had similiar experiences with iPad cursor not behaving correctly in text input fields and what possible solutions there might be. I'm stuck and have no idea how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use touch event? iOS has a bug: you **can't input** in editable iframe if you are listening(or had listened) any touch event(touchstart, touchmove...), I tested this bug occurs even you listen other elements but iframe itself. yes, it's a serious bug, you can check out:
[wysihtml5 issues98](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/98)